# Erase layer of tensorflow

Tags: c++, opencv, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

How could I erase layer of tensorflow?

Example:

```
net = tf.reshape(input, [-1, 128*128])
net = tf.layers.dense(inputs = net, units = 16384, activation = tf.nn.relu)
net = tf.layers.dropout(net, training = is_training, name ="erase_later")    
net = tf.layers.dense(inputs = net, units = 8, name = 'regression_output')
```

I want to erase the layer "erase_later" after I load them, how could I do it?
Anything like erase or pop out function exist?

```
net.erase("erase_later")
```

Why do I want to remove it?Because opencv dnn cannot load the network if dense layer are there.

Edit : I want to remove the layer after  loading the weights of the trained model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you're building the graph before loading the weights of the trained model.

In this case, you can actually remove the "erase_later" layer just avoiding the declaring it.

For example, supposing that `is_training` is a boolean variable, you can do:

```
net = tf.reshape(input, [-1, 128*128])
net = tf.layers.dense(inputs = net, units = 16384, activation = tf.nn.relu)
if is_training:
    net = tf.layers.dropout(net, training = is_training, name ="erase_later")    
net = tf.layers.dense(inputs = net, units = 8, name = 'regression_output')
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to remove the layer after loading the weights of the trained model.

Comment: To load the weights you have to define the graph first. If you define a graph without the dropout layer (that has no weight associated) you simply skip that layer. That's the way to proceed. Removing the layer after the loading is impossible (because you can't modify a static graph and tensorflow uses them)

Comment: Is it possible to remove the dropout layer after training(before I save the weights and graph definition)?

Comment: When training, the dropout already add into the network, whole graph is build already, how could I remove dropout from the graph after build?